# Vimeo API: Global Privacy Settings

Tags: vimeo

I believe I already know the answer to my question, but I'll throw it out there just for fun.
Is there anyway in the Vimeo Advanced API to change the global settings for an account?
I would really like to set the Embed Settings approved urls in the global side rather than having to loop through all the videos in an account to add an approved url.

Is there any way to change the global settings for a Vimeo account through the advanced API or is that going to be something implemented in the APIv3?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the advanced api, and may be implemented into API3 in the future.

The plan is to have support for most features on site, but each one needs to be handled securely. I can not assure you that this feature will be implemented in API3, but if you have a specific need it's worth contacting vimeo directly about it : https://vimeo.com/help/contact